# Bootstrap: $('#myModal').modal('show'); causes screen to go black

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

At the end of my body tag, I have a modal:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal mfp-hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="portfolio-modal-dialog bg-white">
    <a class="close-button d-none d-md-block portfolio-modal-dismiss" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <hr class="star-dark mb-5">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And at the beginning of my body tag, I have a script. In this script, I'm trying to show a modal when a google maps marker is clicked. However, when it is clicked, my website crashes with a dim-black screen and no modal shows.

```
window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
               // $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
               //$("#myModa").remove();
               //$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
               // $('body').css('padding-right', '');
               // $('#myModal').modal('show');
               // $('.myModal').modal('show');

                $('#myModal').modal('show');

            });
```

Interestingly, my modal shows perfectly fine when accessing via `href` here:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <a class="portfolio-item d-block mx-auto" href="#myModal">
          <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex position-absolute h-100 w-100">
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

This has to be some type of bug within the Bootstrap Freelancer template. I've read other posts saying that others fixed a similar issue by editing .css files.

Here is my bootstrap.css code

```
    .modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-dialog-centered {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - (0.5rem * 2));
}

.modal-dialog-centered::before {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100vh - (0.5rem * 2));
  content: "";
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.modal-header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.modal-header .close {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem auto;
}

.modal-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

    .modal-body {
     position: relative;
     -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     padding: 1rem;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: end;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
    }

     .modal-footer > :not(:first-child) {
     margin-left: .25rem;
    }

      .modal-footer > :not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: .25rem;
     }

      .modal-scrollbar-measure {
      position: absolute;
      top: -9999px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

     @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .modal-dialog {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 1.75rem auto;
     }
       .modal-dialog-centered {
        min-height: calc(100% - (1.75rem * 2));
     }
       .modal-dialog-centered::before {
       height: calc(100vh - (1.75rem * 2));
     }
      .modal-sm {
      max-width: 300px;
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..backdrop was main issue..so i removed it

```js
// $("#myModal").removeClass("in");
               //$("#myModa").remove();
               //$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
               // $('body').css('padding-right', '');
               // $('#myModal').modal('show');
               // $('.myModal').modal('show');

               $('#myModal').modal('show');
               $(".modal-backdrop").remove();
```

```css
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-open .modal {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1050;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-dialog {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.modal.fade .modal-dialog {
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -25%);
  transform: translate(0, -25%);
}

@media screen and (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  .modal.fade .modal-dialog {
    transition: none;
  }
}

.modal.show .modal-dialog {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.modal-dialog-centered {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: calc(100% - (0.5rem * 2));
}

.modal-dialog-centered::before {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100vh - (0.5rem * 2));
  content: "";
}

.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: auto;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  outline: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}

.modal-backdrop.fade {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.modal-header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-align: start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.3rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.modal-header .close {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: -1rem -1rem -1rem auto;
}

.modal-title {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

    .modal-body {
     position: relative;
     -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
     padding: 1rem;
    }

    .modal-footer {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
     -ms-flex-pack: end;
     justify-content: flex-end;
     padding: 1rem;
     border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
    }

     .modal-footer > :not(:first-child) {
     margin-left: .25rem;
    }

      .modal-footer > :not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: .25rem;
     }

      .modal-scrollbar-measure {
      position: absolute;
      top: -9999px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }

     @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .modal-dialog {
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 1.75rem auto;
     }
       .modal-dialog-centered {
        min-height: calc(100% - (1.75rem * 2));
     }
       .modal-dialog-centered::before {
       height: calc(100vh - (1.75rem * 2));
     }
      .modal-sm {
      max-width: 300px;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="portfolio-modal mfp-hide modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="portfolio-modal-dialog bg-white">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close-button d-none d-md-block portfolio-modal-dismiss" href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-3x fa-times"></i>
    </a>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        helloooo
          <hr class="star-dark mb-5">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, haven't solved yet. What exactly did you change in the .css code?

Comment: $(".modal-backdrop").remove() added in js..once i have faced the same issue so i have solved it by adding this

Comment: When I click the marker, The Black screen goes away, however, my website still freezes and the model does not show.

Comment: haha no sorry, I meant Google Maps Marker, like `window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {}`

Comment: oh okay..so want to open this pop-up on that click event?? like you have posted on the question? you are showing the model

Comment: Exactly. When I attempt to show it via javascript, I get the error. But when I show it via html. It works good.

Comment: okay but after adding that line which I have suggested..that screen issue is resolved right? now the problem is even after the closing of that popup you site freezes which means pop up is not closing correctly.. is it?